# Heroku: Deploying Django Rest Framework + Vue

Tags: django, heroku, vue.js, vuejs2, web-deployment

I have a project made with Django (only DRF API) and Vue js.
I have this project structure:

```
root_directory/
├── project_name/
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── ...
├── front_end/
│   ├── ... vue files generated with CLI 3 ...
└── api/
    └── ... api app files ...
```

I want to deploy this project using heroku and my biggest problem is: I don't know how to serve static files (vue app files).

In heroku docs is specified that I should use [django staticfiles serving](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/) with whitenoise package (apart from hosting them in S3).

But here comes another problem: vue-cli provided me a `index.html` file where everything gets injected when I run `npm run build`, so I can't access `{% static 'example.js' %}` in `index.html` directly, cause it is not the `index.html` that I should use, it is the one in `dist/` folder, of course. But there everything gets minified and too complicated for me to handle. I think `npm run build` would throw an error if it sees something like `{% %}` in `public/index.html`.

I can't figure out how can I manage to deploy this project with heroku.
What would be the best practice to deploy it in this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to seperate the front- and backend completely? Provide the data (e. g. JSON) via REST API with Django in one app and consume the data with Vue in another app.

Comment: Do you mean I should use a CDN for static files (Vue files) and configure a CORS for backend and that's it?

Comment: Kinda, just host two different applications. As you mentioned Heroku: Create two Heroku projects, one for the Django app and one for the Vue app. Vue has to be configered via a `server.js` file for example. There a lot of tutorials on how to "Deploy Django app to Heroku" and "Deploy Vue app to Heroku".

Comment: Oh, this might be a viable solution. I've never thought about deploying Vue app separately into a different server. You can post the solution. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides mixing up both applications, you could host your Django app and Vue app separated from each other.

Use Django to connect to a database and provide the data (e. g. JSON) via REST API (backend).

*Consume* the data from the REST endpoints with your Vue app (frontend).

Here are some starting points (as you mentioned Heroku):

> Deploy Django:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python

> Deploy Vue:

https://medium.com/netscape/deploying-a-vue-js-2-x-app-to-heroku-in-5-steps-tutorial-a69845ace489

> Some nice library to consume the data from the REST API with Vue:

https://github.com/axios/axios

Answer (score 2):

add  this to your Middleware in settings.py

```
'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
```

make sure you add this `STATICFILES_DIRS` and `STATICFILES_STORAGE`    in your `settings.py` after `STATIC_URL`

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

Note: make sure you install this: `pip install django-heroku`

Comment: That is not the problem, I know how to configure static files for django. I do not know how to serve this specific project, having Vue files in a separate folder.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check - Timestrap Application ( https://github.com/overshard/timestrap). They do have Heroku based demo instance: https://timestrap.herokuapp.com/

This Application is based on Vuejs and Django - it will give good idea on how to go about it.

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to handle this using WhiteNoise 4.0 and above and a few settings. For example:

```
# Enable this so that WhiteNoise will serve `index.html` files at the directory root
WHITENOISE_INDEX_FILE = True

# Set this to wherever npm puts your final files
WHITENOISE_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'dist')
```

Comment: The problem is not serving `index.html`, since that's done with django view. The problem is that I do not know how to get js/css files in `index.html` since I don't have access to `{% static 'path/to/js/and/css/files' %}` inside `public/index.html` and neither are js/css files injected. I guess the only thing I can do is to manually modify `dist/index.html` and add the static tag everywhere's needed.